# Ruby on Rails: SQL query is wrong while limiting user endorsements a month

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I wanted to make that the user can endorse each user once a month and 3 users in total a month.

First of all, got a method in user model:

```
# Returns true if the current user is endorsing the other user.
  def endorsing?(other_user)
    endorsing.include?(other_user)
  end
```

Want to slightly change it to check if the user already endorsed the user this month.
I belive it needs to look something like this:

```
def endorsing?(other_user)
    endorsing.where(:created_at => (Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month..Time.zone.now)).include?(other_user)
end
```

But that is obviously wrong cause it gives me following SQL query:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "endorsements" 
ON "users"."id" = "endorsements"."endorsed_id"
WHERE "endorsements"."endorser_id" = ? AND ("users"."created_at" BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000000' AND '2016-01-26 17:15:53.700307')  [["endorser_id", 1]]
```

the `"users"."created_at"` should be `"endorsements"."created_at"`

How do I do that?

Same counts for the limit problem I've got:

```
def endorsement_count_within_limit?
    if endorser.endorsing.where(:created_at => (Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month..Time.zone.now)).count >= 3
      errors.add(:base, "Exceeded endorse limit (3) this month")
    end
  end
```

Which gives:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "endorsements"
ON "users"."id" = "endorsements"."endorsed_id"
WHERE "endorsements"."endorser_id" = ? AND ("users"."created_at" BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000000' AND '2016-01-26 17:15:53.708638' [["endorser_id", 1]]
```

Same problem, users.created should be endorsements.created

I have no idea how to fix that, And bright ideas?

Below i'll paste my controllers, models and partials that use the methods to render forms for endorsing:

---

Endorsements model:

```
class Endorsement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :endorser, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :endorsed, class_name: "User"
  validates :endorser_id, presence: true
  validates :endorsed_id, presence: true
  validates :comment, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140}
  validate :endorsement_count_within_limit?, :on => :create

  def endorsement_count_within_limit?
    if endorser.endorsing.where(:created_at => (Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month..Time.zone.now)).count >= 3
      errors.add(:base, "Exceeded endorse limit (3) this month")
    end
  end

end
```

Endorsements controller:

```
class EndorsementsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user

  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:endorsed_id])
    comment = params[:endorsement][:comment]
    current_user.endorse(@user, comment)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = Endorsement.find(params[:id]).endorsed
    current_user.unendorse(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end

end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :active_endorsements, class_name: "Endorsement",
                                 foreign_key: "endorser_id",
                                 dependent: :destroy
  has_many :passive_endorsements, class_name:  "Endorsement",
                                  foreign_key: "endorsed_id",
                                  dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :endorsing, through: :active_endorsements, source: :endorsed
  has_many :endorsers, through: :passive_endorsements, source: :endorser


.
.
.
  # Endorses a user.
  def endorse(other_user, comment)
    active_endorsements.create(endorsed_id: other_user.id, comment: comment)
  end

  # Unendorses a user.
  def unendorse(other_user)
    active_endorsements.find_by(endorsed_id: other_user.id).destroy
  end

  # Returns true if the current user is endorsing the other user.
  def endorsing?(other_user)
    endorsing.where(:created_at => (Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month..Time.zone.now)).include?(other_user)
  end

  private
.
.
.

end
```

Partials:

_endorse_form:

```
<% unless current_user?(@user) %>
  <div id="endorse_form_<%= @user.id %>">
  <% if current_user.endorsing?(@user) %>
    <%= render partial: 'shared/unendorse' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render partial: 'shared/endorse'%>
  <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

_endorse:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.active_endorsements.build, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <% if f.object.endorsement_count_within_limit? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
        The form contains <%= pluralize(f.object.errors.count, "error") %>.
      </div>
      <ul>
      <% f.object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% else %>
    <div><%= hidden_field_tag :endorsed_id, @user.id %></div>
    <%= f.submit "Endorse", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <%= f.text_field :comment, class: 'form-control' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

_unendorse:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.active_endorsements.find_by(endorsed_id: @user.id),
             html: { method: :delete },
             remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Remove endorse", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

If you need to look at other files it's available here with some parts missing:https://bitbucket.org/kramarz/pracainzynierska

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try explicitly giving the columns for endorsments in your where statement

```
 endorsing.where(%{
    endorsments.created_at BETWEEN 
    '#{Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month.to_s(:db)}'
    AND
    '#{Time.zone.now.to_s(:db)}'
 })
```

Comment: nope, that gives `SQLite3::SQLException: near "00": syntax error: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "endorsements" ON "users"."id" = "endorsements"."endorsed_id" WHERE "endorsements"."endorser_id" = ? AND (endorsments.created_at BETWEEN 2016-01-01 00:00:00 AND 2016-01-26 18:05:18)`

Comment: Missed semicolon to group the interpolated datetime. updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

At first glance it looks like you need to specify `active_endorsements` or `passive_endorsements` where your examples are using `endorsing`, which references the endorsed `user` *through* the `Endorsement`.

This would all be a little less convoluted if the names were changed to better reflect what each object is. Of course, [naming is much more difficult than it seems](http://arlobelshee.com/good-naming-is-a-process-not-a-single-step/).

---

You might have better luck restructuring your relations like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :outbound_endorsements, class_name: "Endorsement", foreign_key: "endorser_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :inbound_endorsements, class_name:  "Endorsement", foreign_key: "endorsed_id", dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :endorsed_users, through: :outbound_endorsements, source: :endorsed_user
  has_many :endorsing_users, through: :inbound_endorsements, source: :endorsing_user
end

class Endorsement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :endorsing_user, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :endorsed_user, class_name: "User"

  scope :current, -> { where(created_at:  (Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month..Time.zone.now) }
end
```

As for the validation, this is more complex than validating data to be persisted by any single model. In these cases, it's really useful to put this logic in [another object entirely](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/):

```
class ValidatedEndorsement
  attr_reader :endorsing_user, :endorsed_user

  def initialize(endorsing_user, endorsed_user)
    @endorsing_user, @endorsed_user = endorsing_user, endorsed_user
  end

  def valid?
    # note: User -> Endorsement -> Scope -> Count = violation of the
    #       law of demeter; if this works well, refactor appropriately ;)
    if @endorsing_user.outbound_endorsements.current.count >= 3
      # no dice
      return false
    end
    true
  end
end
```

If this object is going to be used in response to a user request, it might be worth your while to consider making this object a *FormObject* that uses the underlying validations of an ActiveRecord model. This is easy to do with [virtus](https://github.com/solnic/virtus), requiring only a few lines to change in the above `ValidatedEndorsement`.

Comment: Youre right. At first glance.. But the queries looks like this now:
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "endorsements" WHERE "endorsements"."endorsed_id" = ? AND ("endorsements"."created_at" BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000000' AND '2016-01-26 17:49:21.897949')  [["endorsed_id", 1]]`

So i've lost the joins, and the sent out endorsed_id is in fact the id of an endors**er** :( This is getting way too complicated, and no clue how to make it work :(

Comment: @Helban Which changes did you make: just the active/passive, or the broader recommended changes below the divider in my answer?

Comment: the first comment was only the active/passive. Now i did the broader changes. I am not really sure where should i put the `ValidatedEndorsement` class to. The file with endorsement model? or totally different folder? I did put it below the endorsement model, did all the necesarry refactoring, reset the database, and when trying to validate in the endorsement controller create action using: `if ValidatedEndorsement.new(current_user, @user).valid?
      flash[:alert] = "failed."` 

I get an error: 

`NoMethodError (undefined method 'current_outbound_endorsements' for #<User:0x0...:`

Comment: @Helban That method comes from this line in the user model: `scope :current_outbound_endorsements`. Is this in place?

Comment: Yes, it is, the scope is in user model like this:
`scope :current_outbound_endorsements, -> { where(created_at:  (Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month..Time.zone.now)) }`

Comment: @Helban Oh. I brainfarted, in a few places. For one, scopes do not create instance methods. I've updated my code.